# Remove elements from response using xpath on Scrapy

Tags: python, python-requests, scrapy

I would like to remove specific elements from scrapy response
Here are my steps

```
scrapy shell example.com
```

```
list = response.xpath(xpath) # len(list) = 220, which means there are multiple target elements exits
```

```
for selector in list:
    selector.remove() # or selector.drop(), not know the difference
```

```
list = response.xpath(xpath) # len(list) = 0, which means removed successfully
```

but when I look up the response.text, the target elements still exist!!!

How to get the correct response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it by initially using the root xpath expression to get the root element of the html.

Then do whatever `drop` operations you need using relative paths from the root element.

Then once you have finished you can use the `root.get()` to grab the resulting html text.

For example, here is some sample html:

`index.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="section">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="link1">...</a></li>
      <li><a href="link2">...</a></li>
      <li><a href="link3">...</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <th>
          <td><a href="link4">...</a></td>
          <td><a href="link5">...</a></td>
        </th>
      </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><a href="link6">...</a></td>
        <td><a href="link7">...</a></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

So with that I call `scrapy shell ./index.html`

```
...
>>> root = response.xpath('/*')
>>> root
[<Selector xpath='/*' data='<html lang="en">\n<head>\n  <meta chars...'>]

>>> root.get()
>>> root = response.xpath('/*')
>>> root
[<Selector xpath='/*' data='<html lang="en">\n<head>\n  <meta chars...'>]
>>> root.get()
'<html lang="en">\n<head>\n  <meta charset="UTF-8">\n  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">\n  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">\n  <title>Document</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n  <div class="section">\n    <ul>\n      <li><a href="link1">...</a></li>\n      <li><a href="link2">...</a></li>\n      <li><a href="link3">...</a></li>\n    </ul>\n  </div>\n  <div>\n    <table>\n      <thead>\n        <th>\n          </th><td><a href="link4">...</a></td>\n          <td><a href="link5">...</a></td>\n        \n      </thead>\n    <tbody>\n      <tr>\n        <td><a href="link6">...</a></td>\n        <td><a href="link7">...</a></td>\n      </tr>\n    </tbody>\n    </table>\n  </div>\n</body>\n</html>'
>>> a_elems = root.xpath('.//a')
>>> len(a_elems)
7
>>> a_elems.drop()
>>> root.xpath('.//a')
[]
>>> root.get()
'<html lang="en">\n<head>\n  <meta charset="UTF-8">\n  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">\n  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">\n  <title>Document</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n  <div class="section">\n    <ul>\n      <li>\n      <li>\n      <li>\n    </ul>\n  </div>\n  <div>\n    <table>\n      <thead>\n        <th>\n          </th><td></td>\n          <td></td>\n        \n</thead>\n    <tbody>\n      <tr>\n        <td></td>\n        <td></td>\n      </tr>\n    </tbody>\n    </table>\n  </div>\n</body>\n</html>'
```

As you can see there are no more `<a>` elements in the sample html.

---

p.s. the difference between `remove` and `drop` is that `remove` is deprecated and `drop` isn't.